# What's the name of this type of connector used for high current

Tags: connector

The connector below often found on equipments with high current output. What's the name of it? And what's the other end to mate with it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They look like connectors for banana plugs. Notched but still banana plugs.

Comment: The second picture has a partial name, do you know who makes it? Could you find their manual, might be in there.

Comment: The page of the second picture is https://www.omicronenergy.com/en/products/all/primary-testing-monitoring/cp-cb2/, but I can't find the names, it only states "plug" etc....

Comment: I think that must be some type of welding cable pin jack. The other end would be large diameter pin with a side protrusion that is part of a twist-lock mechanism.

Comment: Why not just call Omicon and ask? This doesn't look like cheap crap...

Comment: All I found was "High current cable set (Order number: VEHK 0610)" but couldn't find anything about what that is...

Comment: The connectors may be manufactured by or for Omicron and available only from them. There are somewhat similar connectors used for welding equipment.

Comment: The first picture comes from another vendor, so it's may not available only from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of this type of connector seems to be single-conductor, pin and sleeve, connector or plug. Information is available online for similar systems by Crouse-Hinds called Cam-Lok and Pos-Lok. Crouse-Hinds is a subsidiary of Cooper Industries which is a subsidiary of Eaton Corp. Other possible manufacturers or brands include Legrand, Killark, Hubbell and Leviton. These items may not be very widely marketed. Different variations of a given connector system may be used by individual equipment manufacturers for specific types of equipment.

The equipment referenced in the question seems to be utility power distribution test equipment. Other types of equipment or industries that may each use a different variation of the same thing may include welders, watercraft shore power, aircraft ground power, theatrical event power, industrial test power and others. Even if more than one equipment OEM uses exactly the same plug type, the plug manufacturers may not sell the the plugs through distribution channels.